# Update data on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to update data on a `matplolib` plot, thus I have patched code from several examples. Just for illustration purpose, I have two different matrix data which will be plotted in two different subplots **alternately**. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

matrix1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
matrix2 = np.array([[2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13]])

plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(221)

def update(mat1, mat2):

    ax1.plot(mat1.T, 'ro', color='red')
    ax2.plot(mat2.T, 'ro', color='blue')

    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()

    time.sleep(1)
    
    ax1.plot(mat2.T, 'ro', color='blue')
    ax2.plot(mat1.T, 'ro', color='red')

    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()

    time.sleep(1)

for i in range(10):
    update(matrix1, matrix2)
```

which obviously doesn't work. As it is illustrated below, data of matrix1 *(red)* and matrix2 *(blue)* should appear not simultaneously in each subplot, but one matrix an each subplot and reverse position after each second.

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**P.S.** I know that there are similar questions which I tried to consult, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

`matplotlib` provides an [animation library](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/animation_api.html). It is better to use it since the animation event loop has better error handling, e.g. when you close the plot figure when run from a script.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

matrix1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
matrix2 = np.array([[2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13]])
matrices = [matrix1.T, matrix2.T]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
lines1 = ax1.plot(matrices[0], 'ro', color='red')
lines2 = ax2.plot(matrices[1], 'ro', color='blue')

def update(frame):
    matrices.reverse()
    for index, l1, l2 in zip(range(3), lines1, lines2):
        l1.set_data(range(4), matrices[0][:, index])
        l2.set_data(range(4), matrices[1][:, index])

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=range(10), interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

In order to use `FuncAnimation()`, you keep track of the `Line2D` object(s) returned by `ax.plot()`, in this case `lines1` and `lines2` are lists of `Line2D` objects (6 in total since each matrix has three rows). Then in the `update()` function, you can `.set_data()` or do whatever you need to change the data how you like. You can check out the [documentation for `Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html) on how to change the plotted data's color with `line.set_color()` and more.

Comment: I copied the code but nothing happens, no plot appears. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @user3060854 I forgot `plt.show()` It should work with that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

from numpy.core.shape_base import block

matrix1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
matrix2 = np.array([[2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9],[10,11,12,13]])

plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(221)



def update(mat1, mat2):

    ax1.plot(mat1.T, 'ro', color='red')
    ax2.plot(mat2.T, 'ro', color='blue')
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(1)
    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()
    
    ax1.plot(mat2.T, 'ro', color='blue')
    ax2.plot(mat1.T, 'ro', color='red')
    plt.show()
    plt.pause(1)

    ax1.clear()
    ax2.clear()

for i in range(10):
    update(matrix1, matrix2)
```